# Unable to add a 64-bit MSI package to a Group Policy Object on Windows Server 2003 (32 bit)

Tags: group-policy, msi, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to remotely install a 32 -bit MSI and a 64-bit MSI, using Group Policies in Windows Server 2003 (32 bit).

I've created a distribution point and a Group Policy Object. When I try to "Assign a Package" and pick the 32-bit MSI,  everything works fine. However, when I try to assign a 64-bit MSI, I get this error:

"Add operation failed. Unable to extract deployment information from
the package. Run validation on the package to ensure that the package
is correct"

Any idea what might be going on here? Is it even possible to remotely install 64-bit MSI via group policies using Windows Server 2003 (32 Bit)?

Comment: As far as I know it is possible but I've now easy way to verify. Are either of the MSI's installed on the computer you are creating the GPO on? That used to cause problems/may still cause problems.

Comment: Nope. MSIs are not installed on the Windows Server 2003 machine

Comment: Have you tried the failing package on another server or a different 64bit MSI on this server?  I don't have experience doing this on 2003, but have not had issues doing it on 2008 32bit.

Comment: I have just tried the failing package on Windows Server 2008 (32 bit). I still see the same error. The MSI as such, works well if I install it manually on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

(old question I know, but maybe a useful answer to someone)

You can't use a Group Policy Editor on a 32bit machine to assign a 64bit application.  You need to run Group Policy Editor on a 64bit machine to make the assignment. (even if it is just a client machine accessing the same 32 bit server)

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I had this problem a while back and it was caused by the file path being too long. What happens if you shorten the UNC path to the MSI and try again? If it is still too long, you could also create the admin install point using the *SHORTFILENAMES=TRUE* switch?